# Load properties in Eclipse Dynamic web project?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

CODE :

```
public void initialize() {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    try {

        p.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("database.properties"));

        classForname = p.getProperty("classForname");
        url = p.getProperty("url");
        username = p.getProperty("user");
        password = p.getProperty("password");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(classForname);
    System.out.println(url);
    System.out.println(username);
    System.out.println(password);
}
```

this code in Netbean work fine all the way.

but when i copy to eclipse it can't load infomation from properties file when run project.

run single that file is ok

i put properties file in default package (Netbean)  and  /src/database.properties(Eclipse)

help me please !!

here is some log :

```
 Apr 04, 2014 3:47:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Login] in context with path [/WebBasic] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Connection is null !
    at my.Dao.ConnectDatabase.getConnect(ConnectDatabase.java:73)
    at my.Dao.UserDAO.checkUser(UserDAO.java:40)
    at my.Servlet.Login.processRequest(Login.java:46)
    at my.Servlet.Login.doGet(Login.java:86)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Do you get an exception? or the code isn't executed at all?

Comment: i got a exception that i define, it because there's no infomation when create a connection. I thing have some differen about path between netbean and eclise.

Comment: Did you or did you not get a FileNotFoundException while reading properties?

Comment: @TanmayPatil: There is no `FileNotFoundException` with `getResourceAsStream()`, it just returns `null`. `p.load(null)` might throw an NPE, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints to debug this:

1. Don't put so many things in a single line:

   ```
   InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("database.properties");
   p.load(stream);
   ```
2. You forgot to close the stream (resource leak)
3. You forgot to check that the stream isn't `null` (= tells you that Java couldn't find the resource)
4. Look in the folder `bin/`. Is there a file `database.properties` in there? Note: You can't do this in Eclipse because the IDE hides the content of that folder. Use your OS's tools.
5. Create a breakpoint in the code and step through it to see what happens.

Comment: thanks for great advice !
can you tell me where the "bin/" is ?
in tomcat or project folder ?
i have "database.properties" in C:\Users\Terminator\Documents\Eclipse Projects\WebBasic\build\classes

Comment: Maybe that's your `bin/` folder. To find out, open the "Project Properties" dialog, go "Java Build Path", open the "Source" tab. The value we look for is under "Output Folder". Note that there can be several of them. It should be enough if the `database.properties` file can be found in one of them (preferably the one which is connected to the source folder in which you edit the file...)